# Mapping photoluminescense spectra based on their peak

Tags: redshift

Do you know any program that can map multiple spectra? To be more specific, I have a lot of spectra that show the emission peak wavelength of a material in different locations of its surface. It can be observed that in some spectra the emission peak deviates from its original peak (redshift/blueshift). So we want to make a mapping of the material's surface based on the deviation of the emission peak wavelength. So, if you happen to know any program that is capable of mapping multiple spectra, let me know. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Like a (pun not intended) 2D color map?

Comment: yes a 2D map basically

Comment: So at each (x,y) point you have the emission peak wavelength. You can now make a color map in many pieces of software, from Excel to Matlab to Origin to ...

Comment: okay I will look into it. Thanks a lot @JonCuster !